# GNU Toolchain required on Ubuntu 13.04 - for offline PC

Tags: software-installation, application-development

I am very new to this site. Recently I have successfully installed Ubuntu-13.04-32Bit-Desktop version on my Dell laptop and IBM PC. Earlier I was developing Qt-5.0.2 based applications on Windows 7. Now I switched to Ubuntu.

To my surprise:

- I did not find GNU Tool chain in Ubuntu 13.04.
- And unfortunately, my systems are not connected to Internet.

How and from where can I download GNU Tool chain as a package and transfer & install them on my laptop and PC? This is really a huge requirement. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools described on page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline which you can use to transfer required packages to your off-line installation.